# What is prototype in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L879) we can find the following piece of code:

```
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
}

interface ErrorConstructor {
    new (message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    prototype: Error;
}

declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;
```

What is the significance of the `prototype` property on `ErrorConstructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special significance of a `prototype` property in TypeScript beyond the normal special significance of the `prototype` property of JavaScript constructors.

In this code, the `prototype` property of the `ErrorConstructor` type/interface is set to ensure that any code that accesses `ErrorConstructor.prototype` directly will get the correct typing information for that property.

In contrast, the `new` signature of `ErrorConstructor` defines what the type of an object created with a `new` call will be. The `new` return value of a constructor and the `prototype` of the constructor are nominally the same types, but JavaScript allows constructors to return values that are not of their own type, so the distinction is necessary for correct typing of all possible JavaScript code.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it appears to me that `ErrorConstructor` interface is not really meant to be used/referenced. It seems that it's there only so that we can "scaffold" type information around the external Error object. In this light, what possible practical reasons would be for accessing `ErrorConstructor.proptotype`?

Comment: Good point. I guess apart from exactly replicating what is defined in the ECMAScript standard (`lib.d.ts` is auto-generated after all), having `prototype` well typed could aid hand-coded extension of the `Error` class.